# Determine if a string is a sequence of dictionary words

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search

This is Leetcode problem 139: "Wordbreak"

> Problem:  Given a non-empty string `s` and a dictionary `wordDict`
>   containing a list of non-empty words, determine if `s` can be segmented
>   into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

Note:

> The same word in the dictionary may be reused multiple times in the
>   segmentation. You may assume the dictionary does not contain duplicate
>   words.

Example:

- Input: s = "applepenapple", wordDict = ["apple", "pen"]
- Output: true

---

Explanation: Return true because "applepenapple" can be segmented as "apple pen apple".
             Note that you are allowed to reuse a dictionary word.
my solution

```
class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
        """


        """

        def prune(i):
            if i == len(s):
                return True
            elif  i >len(s):
                return False
            else:
                for word in wordDict:
                    m = len(word)
                    if s[i:i+m] == word and prune(i+m):
                        return True

                return False
        wordDict.sort(key = lambda x:-len(x))
        return prune(0)
```

I believe the time complexity for my solution to be O(*m*^*n*), where *m* is the amount of words in `wordDict` and *n* is the length of the string `s`. Space wise is just the recursion stack so O(*n*). I'm having a hard time figuring out how to optimize my solution by either using bfs/dfs or dynamic programming. What would I memoize?

Comment: Include the problem description in your post.  Don’t make reviewers search for what “Leetcode 139” is.

Comment: As AJNeufeld indicated, There are always people lazier than you are (no offense meant) and I'm one of these people who will not make that effort to try to figure out what this thing above is about. I'm not an expert and I might not be writing some review on this code (and I might) and certainly I won't given the absence of the description. And just a side note: the use of classes is not meant for a personal style (no offense once more) but if there is no need for using a class, use a regular function and that would be enough in this case.

Comment: @AJNeufeld hey, thanks for pointing that out! Sorry I am still new to this community i did not know.

Comment: @EmadBoctor on LeetCode the template they have you use is a class by default, this is not a choice by OP

Comment: @ C.Nivs yeah, recently this template started to become more common than usual I was wondering why. Thanks for letting me know anyway.

Answer (score 4):

### `"""DocStrings"""`

+1 for adding a doc string to the `wordBreak()` method, but -1 for not having any content in it.

### PEP-008

Your code diverges from the PEP-008 guidelines in several areas:

1. Use `snake_case` for functions and variables, not `mixedCase`.
2. Use a single space around operators (`elif i > len(s):`), not 2 spaces, and then no spaces.
3. Add a blank line between the inner `prune()` function and the outer function, as well as between the `class Solution` and its first method.

Use `pylint` or `pyflakes` or similar to ensure your code follows proper conventions.

### Variable Names

Variable names like `s` are very terse, but since it is given that name in the question, is forgivable.

Variable names like `wordDict` are misleading, and should be avoided!  `wordDict` is actually a `list`, not a `dict`.  Although that name was given in the question, you should correct it to `word_list`, or simply `words` to avoid confusion.  (+1 for the type hint; it helps avoid some confusion.  But rename the parameter anyway.)

`i` is acceptable as a loop index, but there is no obvious loop.  `idx` or `pos` may improve clarity.

`m` is unacceptable.  It in no way suggests it is the length of a word.  Use a more descriptive variable name.

### Dead Code

```
elif i > len(s):
    return False
```

At what point will this branch every be taken?  The only way is if `prune(i+m)` is called when `i+m` is greater than `len(s)`.  But if `m` is the length of `word`, and `s[i:i+m] == word` is true, it is impossible for `i+m` to exceed `len(s)`.  This branch is dead code, and can be removed.

### Algorithmic Improvements

You are sorting your "dictionary" by length, so that you check the longest words first.  However, this doesn't actually guarantee any speed improvements.  At any step, if the next possible word is the shortest one, you've guaranteed it will be the last one checked.  Ditch the sort.

What you want to do is reduce the number of words from the "dictionary" you are testing at each step.  One obvious way would be to turn the "dictionary" into an actual `dict`, say, storing the list of words which start with a given letter:

```
word_dict = {
              "a": ["apple"],
              "p": ["pen"],
            }
```

Or more programmatically:

```
word_dict = defaultdict(list, ((word[:1], word) for word in wordDict))
```

Then at each step, instead of comparing `s[i:i+len(word)]` to each and every `word` in `wordDict`, you would compare to the list of words in `word_dict[s[i:i+1]]`, which should be significantly smaller.

This method will degenerate if all the dictionary words start with the same letter (`["aaaa", "aaab", "aaac", "aaad"]`), but you could handle this by storing the dictionary as a tree structure instead.

Another alternative would be to separate `wordDict` into sets of words of different lengths:

```
words_by_length = { 3: { "pen" }, 5: { "apple" } }
```

Then, at each stage, you could do a single `set` containment test for each word length:

```
for word_length, word_list in words_by_length.items():
    if s[i:i+word_length] in words_list:
        # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This task can be accomplished using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

As an example, for the input `wordDict = ["apple", "pen"]`, one can build a regular expression 
 `r"(apple|pen)+"`, and then match it against the entire input string `"applepenapple"` (use `re.fullmatch`, not `re.match`). The underlying algorithm for regular expression matching is based on a [finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) and is very efficient.

Comment: You have presented an alternate solution, but have not provided any review of the OP's code.  From the [Help Center/Answering](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) "_Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for an improved solution but not a full review. So I did not attempt to provide it.